# DSL for form field definition with field validation

Tags: html, forms, validation, dsl

I am looking for a DSL that will allow me to create field definitions of a dynamic form using either json or XML. Some googling only returned https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform but that seems to be bootstrap specific and doesn't support custom validations etc. Any other alternatives?